# Meaning of /en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //

Tags: sed

I saw this the other day:

```
sed --in-place '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //' /etc/locale.gen
```

I understand it all except the `'/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //'`. I understand `en_US.UTF-8` but what is surrounding it. It looks like RegEx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed                            # stream editor

--in-place                     # save changes to same filename

'/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //'         # program/script for sed 

    /en_US.UTF-8/              # on any line that contains this text
    s/^# //                    # remove any initial 'comment' designator

/etc/locale.gen                # filename to be read then replaced
```

So it uncomments the `en_US.UTF-8` line in file `locale.gen`.

There is a man page for `sed` that explains this. There are many online introductions to sed that would cover this.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand it all except the `'/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //'`

Assuming this is correct, it's removing the `#` and space at the beginning of lines that contain `en_US.UTF-8` somewhere in them.

So it turns this e.g.:

```
# en_US.UTF-8 foo bar
# foo bar en_US.UTF-8
```

Into this:

```
en_US.UTF-8 foo bar
foo bar en_US.UTF-8
```

Breakdown:

- `' '` - Normal part of the `sed` command.
- `/en_US.UTF-8/` - Look for lines with `en_US.UTF-8` in them.
- `s` - subtitute command.
- `/^# /` - Regular expression. If the line starts with `#` and a space...
- `//` - Blank replacement. Turns # and space into... nothing (no character -- deleted!).